# C++ Initialising Object In Class With Variable In Template

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11

I'm trying to initialise a `dMatrix` using the following code.

```
class BpmSolve
{
private:
    const int numZPts;
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, numZPts> dMatrix;

public:
    BpmSolve(numberZPoints);
};

BpmSolve::BpmSolve(int numberZPoints)
    : numZPts(numberZPoints),
{
}
```

The code errors because `numZPts` is a variable.  If I replace `numZPts` with, say, an integer there are no issues.

What's the correct way to initialise this class?  C++11 options are fine.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you plan to set `numZPts`? It has to be a compile time constant, in which case it should be the same for all instances of `BpmSolve`, which means you could do this: `static const int numZPts = 42;`

Comment: What do you mean?  I set it when I initialise the class.  The constructor is below the class header.  I just plan on calling the constructor.

Comment: Well, that is not a compile time constant, so you cannot do that.

Comment: Yes, at compile time the value is not known.  It will change depending on user input.  This is a requirement.

Comment: Looking at the Eigen docs there appears to be a Matrix variant with run time dimensions; that may be what you need (cf. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Eigen::Matrix` is a template, and template arguments must be available at compile time. The value of `numZPts` is not available at compile time - each time you construct a `BpmSolve` object it may have different value of this field, and the value is not known at compile time. So you ask for something which is not possible.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I suppose I'll have to use a dynamic matrix and set its dimensions in the constructor.  I wasn't aware that templates were evaluated at compile time

Comment: @Jean-Luc or make your `BpmSolve` class a template with `int numZPts` as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `numZPts` value isn't defined at compile time. If all instances of that class happen to use constants for that value throughout your code, you could simply turn your class into a template parameterized by it:

```
template <int numZPts>
class BpmSolve {
private:
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, numZPts> dMatrix;
    // [...]

BpmSolve::BpmSolve(){
}
```

Instances become:

```
BpmSolve<init> instance;
```

Instead of

```
BpmSolve instance(init);
```

This might trigger further changes if this class has inheriting children.

Comment: Unfortunately, `numZPts` is not known at compile time.  An arbitrary file will be read by the program, and `numZPts` calculated from that.  I think that means I cannot do this.

Comment: Well, it was worth a try.